# Add TODO: into XAML so that is shows on my task list in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, xaml

Does anyone know how to add todo: items into XAML?

I am in the habit of using //TODO: in my code for things that I have to come back and fix up. I can't seem to find out if this is possible to do in XAML?

I would like to add things to my tasklist that point to XAML. :(

Any idea's would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry to be the one with the bad news, but it is not possible yet.  A [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/395845/add-todo-support-in-xaml.html) has already been created in Microsoft Connect for that feature to be implemented. For now, you'll have to rely on your search.

-D

Comment: Ahh ic, well I hope they can manage nested comments while they are at it :) Thank you so much for letting me know, spent ages trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: The link does not work anymore. But there is a (closed) [suggestion on UserVoice](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-ide/suggestions/2309153-add-support-for-comment-and-todo-metadata-for-the) in the same spirit.

Comment: After 10 years it is still not here :/

Comment: A more recent place to vote: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/add-todo-support-in-xaml/395845

Answer (score 23):

In Visual Studio 2015 and 2017 at least, one can create a ["Shortcut" (VS Docs)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/using-the-task-list?view=vs-2017#shortcuts), which is a Bookmark in code that is tracked as Task by Task list.
Shortcuts can be created in XAML code and are tracked too.

I just create a one line XAML comment and put Shortcut on that line (Ctrl+K, Ctrl+H)

```
<!-- TODO: Color buttons: Delete - red, Edit - yellow, New - green -->
```

This function may exist in earlier VS versions, but I can't verify.

(Yes, I know this is an old question, but it was a first result in Google for this, so I'm adding this breadcrumb for others that may end up here.)

Comment: This also works in VS 2019 